# Livewire - x-model and and wire:model on the same HTML field

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a Livewire  component where I have a select form field.

I want the field to a) be bound to the model, and b) have another HTML field show when the value changes.

I want to use a combination of Livewire for model binding and Alpine.js to react to field changes.

```
<div
    x-data="{ isExtraData : false, display_type : '' }"
    x-init="$watch('display_type', () => { isExtraData = display_type != 'text_field' })"
>
```

I can either have the proper value set on the HTML element, OR I can have the interactivity when I change the value in the drop down, but if I have both (as below) then the value isn't bound to the select field.

```
<select id="display_type" class="form-control mr-2" style="width:auto" wire:model="display_type" x-model="display_type" required>
```

Comment: Could get rid of one of the two model bindings and just use `{ display_type: @entangle('display_type') } https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js

Comment: thanks @SteveO i hadnt seen entangle before!

Answer (score 0):

use sample :

livewire:

```
class Dropdown extends Component

{

    public $showDropdown = false;

 

    public function archive()

    {

        ...

        $this->showDropdown = false;

    }

 

    public function delete()

    {

        ...

        $this->showDropdown = false;

    }

}
```

template :

```
<div x-data="{ open: @entangle('showDropdown') }">

    <button @click="open = true">Show More...</button>

 

    <ul x-show="open" @click.outside="open = false">

        <li><button wire:click="archive">Archive</button></li>

        <li><button wire:click="delete">Delete</button></li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

more :
[enter link description here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js)